# How to deploy parse dashboard to heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I have deployed the parse server on heroku (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) but can't find anything to deploy the parse dashboard on heroku. Any reference is appreciated!!

Comment: Discussion is in progress on the Github's page : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/159

Comment: I was helped by the GitHub issue page commented on above, but it still took me a while before I was able to get a functioning dashboard deployed to Heroku.  In the end, I got it working and documented my steps here: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/17/deploying-parse-dashboard/  I've posted a comment to the issue referenced to see if I might be able to contribute that to the documentation, but for now it's on my personal blog.  Hoping it'll help others who stumble upon this question.

Comment: I try to open appname.herokuapp.com/parse. Browser redirects me to appname.herokuapp.com/apps/appname/browser Not showing parse database.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't have to clone the parse-dashboard repository. Here is a better way using parse-dashboard as a node module.

1. Create a new node app:

   ```
   mkdir my-parse-dashboard
   cd my-parse-dashboard
   npm init
   ```

   Fill out the details it asks for.
2. Create a git repository:

   ```
   git init
   ```

   Additionally you can push this git repository to a remote server (e.g. Bitbucket). Note this repository should be private since it will contain your master key.
3. Install the parse-dashboard package:

   ```
   npm install parse-dashboard --save
   ```
4. Create an `index.js` file with the following line:

   ```
   require('parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/index.js');
   ```
5. Create a parse-dashboard-config.json file which looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "apps": [
       {
         "serverURL": "your parse server url",
         "appId": "your app Id",
         "masterKey": "your master key",
         "appName": "My Parse App"
       }
     ],
     "users": [
       {
         "user":"username",
         "pass":"password"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Update your `package.json` file and add this section (or modify it if it already exists):

   ```
     "scripts": {
       "start": "node ./index.js --config ./parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1"
     }
   ```

   Note: The `allowInsecureHTTP` flag seems to be required on Heroku. Thanks to @nsarafa for this.
7. Commit all your changes and merge them into `master`.
8. Create a new Heroku app: `heroku apps:create my-parse-dashboard`
9. Run `git push heroku master` to deploy your app to Heroku.

Remember to generate a strong password as your dashboard is accessible to anyone on the internet. And make the dashboard only accessible through SSL else your password will be sent in clear text. Read this [tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-CloudFlare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS) on how to force all traffic over SSL on Heroku with Cloudflare for your domain.

Comment: Hmm.. I follow this exactly and get an "Application Error". Any ideas how to debug this? My config files work offline.

Comment: @Muz Run `heroku logs` from your directory and look in the logs why you are getting this error.

Comment: After get "Application Error", I fixed it using ```"scripts": {
    "start": "parse-dashboard --config ./parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1"
  },```

Comment: Thanks for this, what if i want to deploy both Parse Server and also the ParseDashboard, how can i go about this, please.

Comment: I try to open https://appname.herokuapp.com/parse. Browser redirects me to https://appname.herokuapp.com/apps/appname/browser Not showing parse database.

Answer (score 7):

I just managed to get this working. Here are the steps I took.

1. Clone parse-dashboard to your local machine.
2. Run npm install inside that directory.
3. Update package.json and change the "start" script to:

   ```
   "start": "node ./Parse-Dashboard/index.js --config ./Parse-Dashboard     /parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1"
   ```

   (Thanks to nsarafa's answer above for that).
4. Edit your .gitignore file and remove the following three lines:

   ```
   bundles/Parse-Dashboard/public/bundles/Parse-Dashboard/parsedashboard-config.json
   ```
5. Edit your config file in `Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json`, making sure URLs and keys are correct. Here is an example :

   ```
   {
   "apps": [
     {
       "serverURL": "https://dhowung-fjird-52012.herokuapp.com/parse",
       "appId": "myAppId",
       "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
       "appName": "dhowung-fjird-40722"
     }
    ],
   "users": [
     {
      "user":"myUserName",
      "pass":"Str0ng_?Passw0rd"
     }
    ]
   }
   ```
6. Remove the cache from your heroku parse server app :

   ```
    heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false --app yourHerokuParseServerApp
   ```

   if we follow the example above

   ```
    yourHerokuParseServerApp = dhowung-fjird-40722
   ```

   (Again, thanks to nsarafa).
7. Add, commit and push your changes.
8. Deploy to Heroku again using their CLI or the dashboard.

Step 4 was the key for me because I wasn't committing my config file, and it took me a while to realise.

Also, as stated above, make sure you have user logins and passwords in your config file, following the [parse-dashboard docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard):

PS: on your heroku parse server make sure your `SERVER_URL` looks like this `https://yourHerokuParseServerAppName.herokuapp.com/parse`

Comment: Step 4 did it for me as well

Comment: "Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS"

Comment: I try to open https://appname.herokuapp.com/parse. Browser redirects me to https://appname.herokuapp.com/apps/appname/browser Not showing parse database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update brew `brew update`
2. Install heroku-cli `brew install heroku-toolbelt`
3. Login via command line with your heroku credentials `heroku login`
4. Make sure your app is there `heroku list` and note `YOURHEROKUAPPSNAME` containing the parse-dashboard deployment
5. Tell Heroku to ignore the cache from previous deploys `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false --app YOURHEROKUAPPSNAME`
6. Go to your package.json and change `start: node ./Parse-Dashboard/index.js` to `start node./Parse-Dashboard/index.js --config ./Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1"`
7. Delete your Procfile `rm Procfile`
8. Add, commit and merge to your master branch
9. Run `git push heroku master`

The `start` script inside your package.json overrides whatever you declare inside of the Procfile. This process should enable a clean deploy to Heroku. Please be cautious and generate user logins with strong passwords before performing this deployment per the [parse-dashboard documentation](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard).

Comment: Are you running the dashboard on the same Heroku dyno as your parse server?  I'm struggling with getting that to work.

Comment: @listingboat I'm trying to do the same thing and having issues. You had any luck?

Comment: @AlexArgo  Yes, here:
`ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard'),
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    "apps": [
        {
            "serverURL":  serverUrl,
            "appId": process.env.APP_ID,
            "masterKey": process.env.MASTER_KEY,
            "appName": process.env.APP_NAME,
            "production": appSettings.PRODUCTION
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "user": "admin",
            "pass": process.env.PARSE_DASHBOARD_ADMIN_PASSWORD || "password"
        }
    ]
}, true);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
`