# Parse Dashboard - works locally, blank on Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I am running Parse dashboard locally - works fine

Deployed to Heroku (see references below) - it runs but does now load anything (blank screen). No errors in the log - app is up and running.

I have tried to deploy based on the following links:

1. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120176/how-to-deploy-parse-dashboard-to-heroku)
2. [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/deploy-parse-dashboard-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1):

The issues came down to the bundles/ directory not being pushed correctly to git (and thus Heroku).

Make sure you run 'npm install' on your local directory
Make sure you add/commit the entire directory to git.

Comment: just had the same issue, but doing an npm install doesnt change anthing, everything is installed and im commiting everything. Im not trying to get parse dashboard but just my app, which is in node. It was working before, im not comitting node_modules though, anybody got any tips?