# Heroku + Parse Server config

Tags: heroku, parse-server

this is the main config from **index.js** in ParseServer code:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
  classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
}
```

As I understand it, I do not have to change any of these values. No need to hardcode my keys since I can make use of Heroku config vars:

[image]

However, I must be doing something wrong since launching my Heroku app results in a generic error:

[image]

I want to avoid the hardcoding-in-code option. Any ideas?

Heroku app logs:

[image]

Comment: Can you include your full Heroku logs? You've only shown the bottom of them, which makes it impossible to see what the actual error was =)

Comment: never mind, I reinstalled from the Parse Server git and it worked the 2nd time around.

Comment: I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36990765/4831567) when i try to open [this link](https://appname.herokuapp.com/parse). Browser redirects me to [here](https://appname.herokuapp.com/apps/appname/browser). Not showing parse database.

Comment: @Polis please let me know solution if you know. I am stuck